# Basic problems i cant overcome on plotshape() and float variables

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

most probably what im going to ask here is too simple but im not that much good on programming and total newbie on pinescript.
im trying to write a basic strategy, in order to ger algo ready and see if its working before writing whole strategy im writing it as an indicator.
im having a couple of issues. first, series float and integer. in order to over come this i tried some silly idea to define my vars to tw already defined floats, like here:

```
Sar = ta.sar(0.02, 0.02, 0.2)
[BBmiddle, BBupper, BBlower] = ta.bb(close, 20, 2)
SarMid = BBmiddle-BBmiddle
SarMidH = SarMid
stopP = SarMid
```

then used them on my if's like:

```
if Sar[2] > close[2] and Sar[1] < close[1]
    stopP := BBlower,
    takeP1 := open - BBlower
```

and then to better visualize this i used plotshapes like this:

```
plotshape(stopP, color=color.red, style=shape.triangleup, text="Stop Point", location=location.absolute)
plotshape(takeP1, color=color.green, style=shape.triangledown, text="Take Profit Point 1", location=location.absolute)
```

so far so good'ish' but at this stage main problem im having is chart puts these plots to the very bottom of chart as well. im guessing its because i've already defined stopP and takeP1 before but i cant create them inside the if. what would help me to overcome this? thank you in advance

[image: this is how it looks like]

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

`SarMid` is always zero (`BBmiddle-BBmiddle`) at the beginning unless you modify its value somewhere else.

```
SarMid = BBmiddle-BBmiddle  // This is zero
SarMidH = SarMid  // Hence, SarMidH is zero too
stopP = SarMid    // Hence, stopP is zero too
```

You only modify `stopP` when your condition is `true`. Otherwise, it will remain `zero`.

Since you are using `location=location.absolute` when plotting your shape based on `stopP`, it plots those shapes at `zero`

Comment: as is said 'in order to over come this i tried some silly idea to define my vars to tw already defined floats, like here:'
im already aware of that. its just, i couldnt find another way to determine my variables as floats other than this.

Comment: Then tell us what you are trying to do so we can help.